# c++ function types in typedefs

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, generic-programming

Why doesn't the following typedef declaration for a function type compile?

```
typedef void( int ) void_from_int_t;
```

Comment: Maybe `Boost.FunctionTypes` or the _trait_ for functions in `Boost.TypeTraits` (now in C++11) help

Comment: Capital letters makes it easier to read your post.

Comment: I took the liberty to condense your post down a bit. If that's inappropriate, feel free to roll the edit back, and apologies in that case.

Comment: Take note that the C++11 `using` syntax makes it similar to what you have and easier to read.

Comment: I, too, put no effort into posts that are supposed to make people want to help me.

Comment: @KerrekSB *outstanding* edit =P

Comment: Wow, sorry to everyone who was offended by the formatting; I had no idea caps were such a big deal in readability for others.  I really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `typedef void(void_from_int_t)(int);` etc. Declaration follows use, [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), or whatever your favourite mnemonic for this is.

Comment: hey kerrek, thank you very much!  this makes total sense considering the syntax for pointers-to-functions, don't know why i didn't tumble to this.  probably time for some coffee...

Answer (score 0):

In general, to create a type definition, just add `typedef` to a variable definition:

```
// array of ten integers, instance and type
int a[10];
typedef int a_t[10];
// function, declaration and type
void function(int);
typedef void function_t(int);
```

Note that this is a function type, not a function pointer type, which you get by adding a star:

```
function_t* pf = &function;
```